# Confusion about object properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am passing an object's property to a function. This property happens to be an array.

```
object.color[]
```

Is there anyway I can get the name of the object that this property belongs to?

I would like to do that rather than having to pass both the object and the property into the function.

Comment: Sorry that was dumb of me, javascript, I edited the title to note that.

Comment: better to tag it :) which I just did

Comment: It is impossible, name is nothing but an identifier for a programmer and you should never rely on it

Comment: You cannot know what object a property belongs to. The same property could be attached to multiple objects. `var a = {a:1}, b = {b: a}, c = {c: a}` If you pass  `b.b`, it's impossible to know whether your reference came from a, b or c

Comment: if you pass the object, you are also able to access the property inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't do it.  Why not just pass the object only and access the property in the function?

```
var object = {};

object.color = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

doStuff(object);

function doStuff(obj) {
    obj.color.push['purple'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to pass the whole object. Why would you need a *name* of an object enclosing this property? What would you do with it? Are you aware that several variables can point to the same object and several objects can point to the same array?

```
var object2.color = object1.color;
```

When you now pass `object1` and `object2` are both referring to the same `color` array.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get the object name from a property.

Why not pass the object and get it's properties inside your function?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. A javascript object (in this case: the Array) has no "parent" like a DOM node. If you pass the object to a function, the function will only know of the object and nothing else.

```
var myob = { color: ["abc", "def"] };
myfunc(myob.color);
```

is equal to

```
var myarr = ["abc", "def"];
myfunc(myarr);
```

is equal to

```
myfunc(["abc", "def"]);
```

- there is no difference for the `myfunc`.